# Printing elements of a list on new lines

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print the elements of my list onto new lines, but i cant get it to work;

```
printElements :: [String] -> IO()
printElements (x:xs) =  print x (some kind of newline, then loop?) printElements xs
```

So this:

```
["1","2","2","4"]
```

would give:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to program a loop over a list, it's been done already. To loop over a list with a monadic function, you would use [mapM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM) (and its [mapM_](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) variant if you don't care about the result.)

If you use [print](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:print), for `["1","2","3","4"]` you'd get :

```
Prelude> mapM_ print ["1","2","3","4"]
"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
Prelude>
```

[print](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:print) is actually :

```
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
print x = putStrLn (show x)
```

the [show](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:show) function causes the string `"1"` to be converted to `"\"1\""`, [putStrLn](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) prints that and a newline.

If you replace the [print](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:print) by [putStrLn](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn), you remove the conversion step and print directly the string:

```
Prelude> mapM_ putStrLn ["1","2","3","4"]
1
2
3
4
Prelude>
```

Now I would like to offer another solution. The Haskell way of doing things is doing as much as you can in a pure way, and only use IO when you need it.

So in this case we can join all strings to be printed with a `\n`, and print all the strings at once.

To join all the strings there's a handy function : [unlines](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:unlines)

```
Prelude> unlines ["1","2","3","4"]
"1\n2\n3\n4\n"
Prelude>
```

Now you just have to print that; notice that [unlines](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:unlines) put a newline after the last item of the list, so we'll use [putStr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:putStr) instead of [putStrLn](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:show)

```
Prelude> putStr ( unlines ["1","2","3","4"] )
1
2
3
4
Prelude>
```

Comment: I think, even if the output is identical, that unlines is a "more right" solution.

Comment: If the list is very large, does `unlines` use twice as much memory or is Haskell able to be lazy in this case?

Comment: I am also interested in the difference in efficiency between `mapM_ putStrLn` and `putStr . unlines`

Comment: What if I have a list of custom elements? Some tuples in my case.

Comment: If `show` is ok to print your elements, you can use `putStr ( unlines $ map show [(1,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C"),(4,"D")])`  but you can replace show by any funtion that'll take your custom type and return a string.

Comment: To explicitly implement the function requested in the question: `printElements = putStr.unlines`

Answer (score 14):

Your function is:

```
printElements :: [String] -> IO()
printElements [] = return ()
printElements (x:xs) = do putStrLn x
                          printElements xs
```

If you already know about monads, you can use [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amapM_) function:

```
printElements :: [String] -> IO()
printElements = mapM_ putStrLn
```

Note: maybe you would have to read the chapter 8 of [lyah](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output).

Comment: `printElements (x:xs) = putStrLn x >> printElements xs` is another way to write the first function.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of explicit recursion, you can use [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) to call `putStrLn` for every element. It works like the regular `map` for lists, but is used with a monadic function (thus the "M"). The underscore variant is used when you only care about the side-effect (in this case, printing) and don't care about the result of the mapped function.

```
printElements :: [String] -> IO ()
printElements = mapM_ putStrLn
```