# Haskell beginner, trying to output a list

Tags: haskell

I suppose everyone here already has seen one of these (or at least a similar) question, still I need to ask because I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere (mostly because I don't know what exactly I should be looking for)

I wrote this tiny script, in which printTriangle is supposed to print out the pascal triangle.

```
fac = product . enumFromTo 2

binomial n k  = (product (drop (k-1) [2..n])) `div` (fac (n-k))

pascalTriangle maxRow = 
               do row<-[0..maxRow-1]
                  return (binomialRow row)
                  where
                  binomialRow row = 
                              do k<-[0..row]
                                 return (binomial row k)

printTriangle :: Int -> IO ()
printTriangle rows  = do row<-(triangle)
                         putStrLn (show row)
                         where 
                         triangle = pascalTriangle rows
```

Now for reasons that are probably obvious to the trained eye, but completely shrouded in mystery for me, i get the following error when trying to load this in ghci:

```
   Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `[[Int]]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: row <- (triangle)
    In the expression:
      do { row <- (triangle);
           putStrLn (show row) }
    In 
an equation for `printTriangle':
            printTriangle rows
              = do { row <- (triangle);
                     putStrLn (show row) }
              where
                  triangle = pascalTriangle rows
```

what im trying to do is something like I call printTriangle like this:

```
printTriangle 3
```

and I get this output:

```
[1]
[1,1]
[1,2,1]
```

If anyone could explain to me why what I'm doing here doesn't work (to be honest, I am not TOO sure what exactly I am doing here; I am used to imperative languages and this whole functional programming thingy is still mighty confusing to me), and how I could do it in a less dumb fashion that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said in a comment that you thought lists were monads, but now you're not sure -- well, you're right, lists *are* monads!  So then why doesn't your code work?

Well, because `IO` is also a monad.  So when the compiler sees `printTriangle :: Int -> IO ()`, and then do-notation, it says "Aha!  I know what to do!  He's using the IO monad!"  Try to imagine its shock and dispair when it discovers that instead of IO monads, it finds list monads inside!

So that's the problem:  to print, and deal with the outside world, you need to use the IO monad; inside the function, you're trying to use lists as the monad.

Let's see how this is a problem.  do-notation is Haskell's syntactic sugar to lure us into its cake house and eat us .... I mean it's syntactic sugar for `>>=` (pronounced bind) to lure us into using monads (and enjoying it).  So let's write `printTriangle` using bind:

```
printTriangle rows = (pascalTriangle rows) >>= (\row -> 
                     putStrLn $ show row)
```

Okay, that was straightforward.  Now do we see any problems?  Well, lets look at the types.  What's the type of bind?  Hoogle says: `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.  Okay, thanks Hoogle.  So basically, bind wants a monad type wrapping a type a personality, a function that turns a type a personality into (the same) monad type wrapping a type-b personality, and ends up with (the same) monad type wrapping a type-b personality.

So in our `printTriangle`, what do we have?

- `pascalTriangle rows :: [[Int]]` -- so our monad is `[]`, and the personality is `[Int]`
- `(\row -> putStrLn $ show row) :: [Int] -> IO ()` -- here the monad is IO, and the personality is `()`

Well, crap.  Hoogle was very clear when it told us that we had to match our monad types, and instead, we've given `>>=` a list monad, and a function that produces an IO monad.  This makes Haskell behave like a little kid:  it closes its eyes and stomps on the floor screaming "No! No! No!" and won't even look at your program, much less compile it.

---

So how do we appease Haskell?  Well, others have already mentioned `mapM_`.  And adding explicit type signatures to top-level functions is also a good idea -- it can sometimes help you to get compile errors sooner, rather than later (and get them you will; this is Haskell after all :) ), which makes it much much easier to understand the error messages.

I'd suggest writing a function that turns your `[[Int]]` into a string, and then printing the string out separately.  By separating the conversion into a string from the IO-nastiness, this will allow you to get on with learning Haskell and not have to worry about `mapM_` & friends until you're good and ready.

```
showTriangle :: [[Int]] -> String
showTriangle triangle = concatMap (\line -> show line ++ "\n") triangle
```

or

```
showTriangle = concatMap (\line -> show line ++ "\n")
```

Then `printTriangle` is a lot easier:

```
printTriangle :: Int -> IO ()
printTriangle rows = putStrLn (showTriangle $ pascalTriangle rows)
```

or

```
printTriangle = putStrLn . showTriangle . pascalTriangle
```

Comment: Wow, that was exactly what I was looking for - thanks, I kinda get what's going on now.

Comment: @Cubic -- if you're interested in learning more about Haskell, but need a good resource, check out `Learn You A Haskell`.  A really fun-to-read, not to mention in-depth, treatment of Haskell and its idioms.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print elements of a list on new lines you shall see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289779/printing-elements-of-a-list-on-new-lines) question.

So

```
printTriangle rows  = mapM_ print $ pascalTriangle rows
```

And

```
λ> printTriangle 3
[1]
[1,1]
[1,2,1]
```

Finally, what you're asking for is seems to be [mapM_](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM-95-).

Comment: This works, but I still have no idea what's actually going on

Comment: (that is, of course I understand what mapM does (at least I think I do - pretty much the same thing as map, just with monads, right?), but I'd still like to know why exactly I'd get that error message - I get type errors all the time in Haskell, so I'd figured that's what I need to focus on right now)

Comment: Actually, I'm a beginner too. One think, than I can tell, is using `<-` and 'rows' parameter in 'printTriangle' is not much validly. So, for example, when you remove one of them, you will got workable code (which actually doing not what you want and looking pretty weird). Like that http://hpaste.org/53912

Comment: @dmitry.malikov -- that's because there's two different monads, `[]` and `IO`.  You need something more advanced (i.e. monad transformers) to mix them.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I'm coding in Haskell I always try declare the types of at least the top-level definitions. Not only does it help by documenting your functions, but also makes it easier to catch type errors. So pascalTriangle has the following type:

```
pascalTriangle :: Int -> [[Int]]
```

When the compiler sees the lines:

```
row<-(triangle)
...
where 
triangle = pascalTriangle rows
```

it will infer that triangle has type:

```
triangle :: [[Int]]
```

The <- operator expects it's right-hand argument to be a monad. Because you declared your function to work on IO monad, the compiler expected that triangle had the type:

```
triangle :: IO something
```

Which clearly does not match type [[Int]]. And that's kind of what the compiler is trying to tell in it's own twisted way.

As others have stated, that style of coding is not idiomatic Haskell. It looks like the kind of code I would produce in my early Haskell days, when I still had an "imperative-oriented" mind. If you try to put aside imperative style of thinking, and open your mind to the functional style, you will find that you can solve most of your problems in a very elegant and tidy fashion.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be something like this. I think the problem is that I still don't quite get the difference between a Monad and a normal function (i thought I could use a list as a monad - quite apparently that's wrong) 

oh, and i'd very much like to open my mind to the functional style, but i don't really know what a functional approach to most problems would look like...

Comment: You can use list as a monad. It's just that in this case the compiler expected the IO monad, and you are giving it the list monad. Monads are not an easy to grasp concept. In case you've missed them, here are some nice resources that might help you:

http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/docs/daume02yaht.pdf,
http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/,
http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/

Answer (score 0):

try the following from the ghci-prompt:

```
> let {pascal 1 = [1]; pascal n = zipWith (+) (l++[0]) (0:l) where l = pascal (n-1)}
> putStr $ concatMap ((++"\n") . show . pascal) [1..20]
```

Your code is very unidiomatic Haskell. In Haskell you use higher order function to build other function. That way you can write very concise code.

Here i combine two list lazily using zipWith to produce the next row of pascals triangle pretty much the way you would compute it by hand. Then concatMap is used to produce a printable string of the triangles which is printed by putStr.

Comment: Well, he *is* using the list monad and point-free style. Instead of trying to improve his code further (it's pretty good for a beginner, I'd say), how about telling him what's cauing the actual error message he sees?

Comment: The pascal triangle wasn't the final goal, I actually wanted to write a function to calculate the binomial distribution so I had my binomial function for that, and I wanted to learn Haskell IO with the triangle as an example. Also, I wouldn't know what's idiomatic or not because I barely know the idiom.