# the statement <- doesn't compile for Maybe

Tags: haskell

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as LHashMap
import Network.HTTP.Types

getJSONObject :: String -> IO Object
--.............

main = do
  jsonObject <- getJSONObject "example.com"
  String a <- LHashMap.lookup "some_key" jsonObject -- doesn't compile
  --.....................................
```

The error is:

```
Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO Value
      Actual type: Maybe Value
```

Indeed, `LHashMap.lookup` returns `Maybe`, not `IO`. But shouldn't `<-` work with `Monads` like `Maybe`?
How do I make it work?

**UPDATE**:
According to the error above, the code below should not work due to the same thing:

```
let toPrint = do 
                Object jsonObject <- decode $ responseBody res :: Maybe Value
                Object jsonObject2 <- LHashMap.lookup "key1" jsonObject
                Object jsonObject3 <- LHashMap.lookup "key2" jsonObject2
                Array d <- LHashMap.lookup "key3" jsonObject3
                String val <- return $ d ! 1
                return val
  case toPrint of
    Just a -> IO.putStrLn a
    _ -> error "Unexpected JSON"
```

But it does work.

Comment: Might wanna look at a similar question I asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100514/haskell-beginner-trying-to-output-a-list - the question is superficially a different one, but it's exactly the same problem except with `[]` instead of `Maybe`.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the code in your update should fail. The answers correctly state that the problem in your original code is that you can't mix different monads in the same do-block. In the code you posted, everything in the do-block is in the `Maybe` monad so there's no issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the monadic values in do-notation need to be from the same Monad.  It's easy to see this if you desugar the do notation:

```
main = getJSONObject "example.com" >>= (\jsonObject ->
       LHashMap.lookup "some_key" jsonObject >>= (\String a -> ... ))
```

And look at the type of `>>=`

```
>>= :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Note that though the parameter `m` makes `>>=` polymorphic, it's the same `m` for both arguments and the return value.

In particular, that means that the typechecker requires that `getJSONObject "example.com"` return a value in the same monad that `LHashMap.lookup "some_key" jsonObject >>= (\String a -> ...)` does, which requires that `LHashMap.lookup "some_key" jsonObject` be in that same monad. And thus your error.

You need to figure out how you want to handle failure:

1. You could just make it into a pattern-match exception by using a `let` statment instead of a bind (not recommended):

   ```
   % cat Temp.hs
   module Main where

   main = do
     let Just x = Nothing
     putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ x

   % runhaskell Temp.hs
   Temp.hs: Temp.hs:4:7-22: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Data.Maybe.Just x
   %
   ```
2. You could make it into a failure in the IO monad, which would make it into a slightly different exceptio (also not recommended)n

   ```
   % cat Temp.hs
   module Main where

   main = do
     Just x <- return Nothing
     putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ x
   % runhaskell Temp.hs
   Temp.hs: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at Temp.hs:4:3-8)
   %
   ```
3. You could use a `case` statement (recommended):

   ```
   % cat Temp.hs
   module Main where

   main = do
     case Nothing of
       Nothing -> return ()
       Just x  -> putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ x
   % runhaskell Temp.hs
   %
   ```

Answer (score 5):

In a `do` block the monad that you use is meant to be homogenous, since it desugars to

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Since the `m` is consistent throughout bind, we also have to be consistent with it throughout our block.

the correct solution here is to handle the `maybe` in a pure way, and not treat it "monadically". A simple solution might be to just use a case expression

```
 case LHashMap.lookup "some_key" jsonObject of
    Just res -> some IO here
    Nothing  -> handle failure here
```

or just to smash that into an expression with

```
 maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

Comment: `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` - could you please show me an example?