# Print list elements in new lines

Tags: list, haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm just totally confused with lists and monads, so maybe my question isn't correct or very naive.
I've seen the way to do it using mapM_ func [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289779/printing-elements-of-a-list-on-new-lines):

```
mapM_ print [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I don't know exactly how it works and want to know how can I do this in a way like this:

```
x <- [1, 2, 3]
print x
```

or, if I understood it right:

```
[1, 2, 3] >>= print
```

I understand that [1, 2, 3] has type `[a]` and print has type `Show a => a -> IO ()`. Also I understand that for using monad List we need type `List a` on the left and func with type `a -> List b` on the right. Am I right?
Can you help me with this?

**UPD**. Thanks @MathematicalOrchid for explanation how mapM_ works. From my side I want to explain that the real problem is not printing any results in different lines but do some monadic actions(because now I'm hanging around OpenGL stuff) in a way monad List provides it. But I got that the root of misunderstanding was in mixing monads.

**UPD2**. Thanks everyone for answers. I apologize for this kinda fuzzy question. I dind't exactly know what answer I need and what is the question. It's because I didn't understand some basics. So it's hard to choose "the correct answer" now because every answers have a small peace of what I was looking for. I've decided to choose the closest(although not the most useful now) to what I wanted.

Comment: `forM_` might look a little more familiar.  It just reverses the arguments of `mapM_`.  Try `forM_ [1, 2, 3] print`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning you are using two monads: `List` and `IO`. The reason your `>>=` doesn't work is that you're trying to mix the two.

Comment: @stusmith: yeah, I also just get it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want cannot work this way since you are trying to mix two monads together:

```
do x <- [1,2,3]
   print x
```

Specifically you are mixing the `IO` and the `[]` monads. In do-notation, all the statements should have the type `m a` for some Monad `m`. But in the above code, the first statement has the type `[Integer]` while the second statement has the type `IO ()`.

To get the effect you want you should use the `ListT` monad transformer. [Monad transformers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) allow mixing monads together in a certain order in a stack and combining their effects as needed.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.List

value = do x <- ListT (return [1,2,3])
           lift (print x)
```

This will return a value of type `ListT IO Integer`. To get the `IO` computation out of this transformer, use `runListT`. Which will return a value of type `IO [Integer]`. This will output:

```
GHCI> runListT value
1
2
3
[(),(),()]
```

Which is equivalent to `mapM print [1,2,3]`. To throw away the list and get the effect of `mapM_ print [1,2,3]` you can use `void` from `Control.Monad`.

```
GHCI> void . runListT $ value
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks for ListT. I'm not going to jump into monad transformers now - its time haven't become yet for me. But it's exactly one of what I was looking for.

Comment: @pkuderov I'm glad to help. I know it's a bit advanced for now. But I thought I should add it since it tackles exactly the kind problem you are trying to solve, in general.

Answer (score 12):

You seem to have several things confused here. (In particular, lists form a monad, and I/O forms a different monad.) I will try to clear this up...

First of all, the `print` function takes anything showable and writes it to standard out, followed by a newline. So `print [1, 2, 3]` works just fine, but obviously writes everything on the same line. To write stuff on seperate lines, we need a seperate invocation of `print` for each item. So far, so good.

The `map` function applies a function to every element of a list. So `map print [1, 2, 3]` would apply `print` to each item in the list. *However*, the result is a list of I/O actions. And that's not quite what we're after. We want to *perform* these actions, not list them.

The way to do this is to use the `>>` operator, which chains two I/O actions together (provided you're not interested in their results - and printing something doesn't return anything interesting). So `foldr (>>) (return ())` will take your list of I/O actions and turn it into one single I/O action. This function is in fact already defined; it's called `sequence`.

However, `map` + `sequence` is such a common combination that *this* too is also already defined; it's called `mapM_`. (There's also `mapM`, without the underscore, if you wanted to keep the results. But printing doesn't return anything, so there's no need.)

---

Now, that's why `mapM_` works. Now you ask why several other ways won't work...

```
x <- [1, 2, 3]
print x
```

This doesn't work at all. The first line is in the list monad. But the second line is in the I/O monad. You can't do that. (You will get a rather baffling type checker error.) I should probably point out that this is Haskell's so-called "do-notation", and the above fragment needs the `do` keyword at the front for it to actually be valid syntax:

```
do
  x <- [1, 2, 3]
  print x
```

Either way, it still doesn't work. It *almost* does what `map print [1, 2, 3]` does, but not quite. (As I said, it won't type-check.)

You also suggested `[1, 2, 3] >>= print`, which is identical to the previous snippet. (In fact, the compiler *converts* the former to the latter.) The original doesn't type-check, and this doesn't type-check either, for the same reason.

It's a bit like trying to add a number to a matrix. Numbers are addable things. Matricies are addable things. But you cannot add one to the other because they aren't the same. If that makes sense.

Comment: very clear explanation! But one more question, please. Is there any way to mix monads(jump from one to another)? For now I see at least 2 ways to do some actions "independently" - by mapping throgh map funs(or its monadic reflection) or by putting actions into List monad. Am I right?

Comment: @pkuderov For some particular pairs of monads `m` and `n` there are ways to jump from `m` to `n`, but lists and `IO` are not one such pair. Instead, the usual technique is to create a new monad that has the characteristics of both the monads you want to jump between using monad transformers. There is no monad transformer that allows you to add `IO` effects list-like things, but there [is a transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/logict/0.5.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Logic.html#t:LogicT) that allows you to add nondeterminism (i.e. list-like characteristics) to `IO`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sequence_` to execute `IO` actions in order:

```
sequence_ $ [1, 2, 3] >>= (\x -> [print x])
```

But I think `mapM_` is considerably clearer.

Comment: Just didn't want anyone to think this was a sensible suggestion. Although `sequence` is handy for making a single action out of a list of actions.

Comment: also, `sequence_ $ map print [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to answer your question exactly, because I think the question itself is a little misguided. In particular, using `mapM` or something similar is *the right thing to do* here. Using do notation for this task will only make it more complicated, and I have an aversion to telling people things that aren't *the right things to do*. But I will provide you with an alternative that you might find easier to digest.

If you're coming from an imperative background (ie you're familiar with something like C, Java, Python ...) then you may find it easier to use `forM` rather than `mapM`. The syntax is

```
forM <list of things> <action to perform for each thing>
```

i.e. it's just like a for-each loop! For example:

```
ghci> import Control.Monad
ghci> forM [1,2,3] print
1
2
3
[(),(),()]
```

The list of things is `[1,2,3]` and the action to perform for each thing is `print`. Notice the return value at the end? That's because each call to `print` returns `()`, and those are collected together at the end. If you don't want a return value you use `forM_` instead of `forM`, like this:

```
ghci> forM_ [1,2,3] print
1
2
3
```

Are you ready for the secret? The functions `forM` and `forM_` are just `mapM` and `mapM_` with the arguments reversed, that is:

```
forM list action = mapM action list
```

I often use `forM` in my code because it draws attention to the *function* rather than the *list* which is often what you want. It also looks neater when then function spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably the simplest explanation of how `mapM_` works:

```
main = foldr1 (>>) (map print [1, 2, 3])
```

That is, `print` is applied to each list member and the results are joined using `>>`, so first you get

```
main = foldr1 (>>) [print 1, print 2, print 3]
```

and in the end you get

```
main = print 1 >> print 2 >> print 3
```

A bit more precise explanation is this:

```
main = foldr (>>) (return ()) (map print [1, 2, 3])
```

So in the end you get

```
main = print 1 >> print 2 >> print 3 >> return ()
```

The `return ()` part lets function work with an empty list - `foldr1` just crashes on empty lists the same way `head` and `tail` do.